# Setup RedisCache on IKS

Tags: caching, kubernetes, command-line, redis, iks

I have setup IKS and logged in to one of the container's command line.

I need to execute a script on that container that connects to RedisCache's client.
Here is the script (testScript.py) I want to execute -

```
import redis
r = redis.Redis(host=‘master.some.path.of.redis.url.amazonaws.com’, port=6323, password=‘somePassword’, ssl=True)
r.set(‘foo’, ‘bar’)
value = r.get(‘foo’)
print(value)
```

I need help in understanding how to be able to setup Redis on the IKS.

Comment: can you please describe question more. What is IKS ? or you mean EKS ?

Comment: HarshManvar IKS is IBM cloud. 
@Kirti Gupta do you want to connect from IKS to AWS cloud using script from container? You need specify your intentions and what already you did to achieve it.

Comment: @PjoterS - Once I'm logged into one of the IKS containers, I need to execute the script. The script should connect to AWS Redis Cache (using the Redis host, port and password) and prints 'bar'.

Comment: I have not been able to figure the way to approach that.

Comment: Is there anything else I need to mention here?